# is there any work around for accessing headers in https.onCall function of firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new to firebase and I came to know that the headers cannot be accessed inside an https.onCall function,only option is to use https.onRequest only. May I know if there is any workaround to access headers inside a https.onCall method please.

Comment: What headers do you want to include? Isn't request body helpful?

Comment: Sure, I will with go with request body only, as I need to use callable functions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no workaround - the API does not allow it.  Callable functions take full control over headers on both the client and server according to the [specification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference), and you must accept that if you want to use callable functions.

If you need access to a headers, you should not use callables at all and use normal HTTP functions instead, where you have full control.

Depending on what your use case is, if you must use callable functions, you can instead use the payload of the request to transmit data to your function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information, I will send the data in the request body instead of headers.

Comment: According to this new [PR](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/pull/269/files), now you can access the request inside of `onCall` functions. This is great help for example if you move your existing Cloud functions to work with [GCP API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway)

Answer (score 2):

For the time being, the `rawRequest` is available on the `CallableContext`.

So, you can set a response header with a line like the following:

```js
context.rawRequest.res?.header('X-My-Header', 'CustomValue')
```

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/common_providers_https.callablecontext

Answer (score 0):

You can now read the Headers now, by processing the rawRequest.rawHeaders like this

```js
const headers = {}
if (
    !request ||
    !request.rawRequest ||
    !request.rawRequest.rawHeaders ||
    !request.rawRequest.rawHeaders.length
)
    return { success: false, message: "Invalid request" }

const rawHeaders = request.rawRequest.rawHeaders
for (let i = 0; i < rawHeaders.length; i += 2)
    headers[rawHeaders[i]] = rawHeaders[i + 1]

console.log(headers)
```