# How do I use Firebase AppCheck with httpsCallable functions?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check, angular-standalone-components

I'm using firebase functions like so...

```
exports.sendLicenseAgain = onCall({
  enforceAppCheck: true,
  consumeAppCheckToken: true,
}, async (req) => {
     ...
})
```

and i have this in my angular 17 front end code

```
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from 'firebase/functions';
import { AppCheck, getToken } from '@angular/fire/app-check';
....
...
getToken(this.appCheck).then((token) => {
        const funcs = getFunctions();
        const sendFunc= httpsCallable(funcs, "sendLicenseAgain", { limitedUseAppCheckTokens: true })
        sendFunc({ ... })
```

I get error status 401 because i haven't included the appcheck token. I know I'm supposed to put the token in the headers with 'X-Firebase-AppCheck' in the http request, but I can't find a way to do that with the httpsCallable funciton. Am I missing something?

EDIT: more info on my implementation:
in app.config.ts:

```
importProvidersFrom(provideAppCheck(() => {
      const provider = new ReCaptchaV3Provider("...");
      return initializeAppCheck(undefined, { provider, isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true });
    })),
```

in app.component.ts (because im in a local host env)

```
constructor(){
(<any>window).FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;
}
```

Comment: I think the token should automatically passed with calls once the SDK has been installed correctly. Don't you see them showing up in the logs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/monitor-functions-metrics?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen oh ok- didn't know that its auto included. I do see my calls in the log but its all "failed to validate AppCheck token. FirebaseAppCheckError denied on resource *my project* " and it sends status 401 back to my client. I don't see any headers or tokens there or any payloads at all in the logs.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i updated my post with some extra implementation steps i have done.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, [don't edit questions with a solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387912/can-should-i-edit-my-question-to-an-add-answer).  instead, answer the question as an actual answer and accept it as correct.  This helps readers better understand what the solution is to a particular problem. It's perfectly OK to answer your own question. I've rolled back the question to support this convention. Please post your solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I removed replay protection code from firebase functions and my web app and now it works.

Specifically I removed from the function's index.js:

```
 consumeAppCheckToken: true,
```

And i removed from my web app's httpsCallable invocation:

```
 { limitedUseAppCheckTokens: true }
```

based on no evidence, I'm thinking the error come from using the debug token with the replay protection.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the HTTP headers for a callable function if you're using the Firebase client library to make the call.  In cases where you must absolutely be able to set headers, you can no longer use the Firebase client library to make the request.

See:

- [How to set Authorization header while calling "callable function" on Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204501/how-to-set-authorization-header-while-calling-callable-function-on-firebase)
- [is there any work around for accessing headers in https.onCall function of firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68311684/is-there-any-work-around-for-accessing-headers-in-https-oncall-function-of-fireb)

To use App Check with callable type functions, you don't have to do anything with headers, because the library handles the header for you, as long as you configure the function and the calling code correctly.  Please see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions) for details.  You don't have to do anything else other than what's shown.

Comment: I have done exactly as the documentation says- I don't understand what i'm doing wrong. I've added some more context to  my implmenation in the post edit

Comment: UPDATE: I REMOVED THE REPLAY PROTECTION CODE AND IT WORKS NOW. I guess replay protection doesnt work so well with debug tokens? I dont know

Comment: If you have a solution to the question: *post it as an answer, not as a comment on someone else's answer*.  Also, if the instructions don't work the way you expect, file an issue with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).  The community volunteers of Stack Overflow can't really help you with that.

Comment: I put it in my post as well, but someone removed it cause it wasn't the right spot for it either, thanks for the advice- commented as answer.

Comment: Right, you're not supposed to answer your own question within the question.  There was a comment explaining that with a link read more about why it's a problem. On Stack Overflow, answers are posted separately from questions so they can be upvoted and accepted separately by the community.